# Run multiple inputs through Python function

Tags: python

I'm running multiple floats through a function to generate a scientific notation. However, not all floats are put in at all times (it is randomised) therefore generating an error.

Input:

```
a0,hvt,at,lambd = signify(a0,hvt,at,lambd)
```

Function:

```
def signify(*args):
    rst = []

    for arg in args:
        if arg >= 100.0 or arg <= 0.01:
            arg = '{:.2e}'.format(arg)
            rst.append(arg)
    return rst
```

In other words, 'rst' does not always consist of four elements (thanks for pointing it out Singh).

Is someone willing to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please add example input, output, and the error. And in general - You could either use dummy variable of you insist on receiving the whole 4, or just return a dict. its varias with your usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think you quite understand what the error is. Can you post the error message?

I suspect you trying to assign `a0,hvt,at,lambd = signify(a0,hvt,at,lambd)` is the real culprit, what if "rst" returning from the function does not have 4 elements? That syntax on the left hand side forces the list on the right hand side to be unpacked exactly into 4 elements, and raises a `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)` in a mismatch.

try `result = signify(a0,hvt,at,lambd)` and check output.

Update:

If you want to only modify only some of the 4 terms but allow the rest to pass as-is, you Just need an else portion. Here is how you can think of the entire process.

```
def signify(*args):
    rst = []
    print(args)
    for arg in args:
        if arg >= 100.0 or arg <= 0.01:
            arg = '{:.2e}'.format(arg) #returns a string
            rst.append(arg)
        else:
            rst.append(arg) #take note that this else statement is the same as the last statement of if block
            #also note that args going through else block are not "strings" unlike the if block, which gives a string during ".format()"
    return rst
```

We can improve on this.

```
def signify(*args):
    rst = []
    print(args)
    for arg in args:
        if arg >= 100.0 or arg <= 0.01:
            arg = '{:.2e}'.format(arg)
        rst.append(arg) #note that you may want to typecast to string to maintain uniformity.
        #rst.append(str(arg))
    return rst
```

However, This essentially is the same as applying a function on all args. We can create a function that emphasizes this "working on 1 term" approach.

```
def signify_single(single_arg):
    if single_arg >= 100 or single_arg <= 0.01:
        return '{:.2e}'.format(single_arg)
    return single_arg #or str(single_arg)
a,b,c,d = (signify_single(x) for x in (101,202,303,40))
```

But that makes us realise this is just an if-else statement. They do not have to be ugly necessarily. (PS. That last line is a [list comprehension.](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions))

```
a,b,c,d = ('{:.2e}'.format(x)
          if (x >= 100 or x <= 0.01)
          else x #or str (x)
          for x in (101,202,303,40))
```

The condition can be tweaked around a little to give us a cleaner comprehension.
Note that these can be written in a single line as well if you prefer.

```
a,b,c,d = (x if (0.01 < x < 100) else '{:.2e}'.format(x) for x in (101,202,303,40))
```

You can use any of the styles which looks the cleanest to you, Or explore and find something even better. Just apply it to your case like this.

```
a0,hvt,at,lambd = (x if (0.01 < x < 100) else '{:.2e}'.format(x) for x in (a0,hvt,at,lambd))
```

Comment: You are correct, rst does not always consists of 4 elements. (will add this to the post) But with my limited experience I'm having trouble coming to the right solution (without going all-out with if statements:))

Comment: ok. What is your goal? You want all 4 terms all the time but some of them modified if they match the condition? then you just are missing an `else` statement that passes the terms as-is.

Comment: @Sumerechny Updated, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: amazing! Thanks, especially for the additional explanation.